# How to return plain/text robots.txt in AngularJS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, nopcommerce

I want to return plain/text to http://domain.com/robots.txt

```
asp.net mvc Common controller         

      public ActionResult RobotsTextFile()
        {
            var disallowPaths = new List<string>()
                                    {
                                        "/bin/",
                                        "/content/files/",
                                        "/content/files/exportimport/",
                                        "/country/getstatesbycountryid",
                                        "/install",
                                        "/setproductreviewhelpfulness",
                                    };
            var localizableDisallowPaths = new List<string>()
                                               {
                                                   "/addproducttocart/catalog/",
                                                   "/addproducttocart/details/",
                                                   "/boards/forumwatch",                                                  
                                                   "/deletepm",
                                                   "/emailwishlist",
                                                   "/inboxupdate",
                                                   ...
                                               };


            const string newLine = "\r\n"; //Environment.NewLine
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("User-agent: *");
            sb.Append(newLine);
            //sitemaps
            if (_localizationSettings.SeoFriendlyUrlsForLanguagesEnabled)
            {
                //URLs are localizable. Append SEO code
                foreach (var language in _languageService.GetAllLanguages(storeId: _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id))
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("Sitemap: {0}{1}/sitemap.xml", _storeContext.CurrentStore.Url, language.UniqueSeoCode);
                    sb.Append(newLine);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //localizable paths (without SEO code)
                sb.AppendFormat("Sitemap: {0}sitemap.xml", _storeContext.CurrentStore.Url);
                sb.Append(newLine);
            }

            //usual paths
            foreach (var path in disallowPaths)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("Disallow: {0}", path);
                sb.Append(newLine);
            }
            //localizable paths (without SEO code)
            foreach (var path in localizableDisallowPaths)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("Disallow: {0}", path);
                sb.Append(newLine);
            }
            if (_localizationSettings.SeoFriendlyUrlsForLanguagesEnabled)
            {
                //URLs are localizable. Append SEO code
                foreach (var language in _languageService.GetAllLanguages(storeId: _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id))
                {
                    foreach (var path in localizableDisallowPaths)
                    {
                        sb.AppendFormat("Disallow: {0}{1}", language.UniqueSeoCode, path);
                        sb.Append(newLine);
                    }
                }
            }

            Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            Response.Write(sb.ToString());
            return null;
        }
```

Angularjs View

```
          <html> <body>... script code here.. 
        <div class="content col-lg-9">
                    <div ui-view="main" class="shuffle-animation"></div>
                </div>
       <footer>...</footer>
    </body></html
```

ui.router:

```
$stateProvider           
                .state('robots', {
                    url: '/robots.txt',
                    views: {
                        '@': {
                            templateUrl: '/App/Main/layouts/_ColumnsTwo.html'
                        },
                        'main@root': {
                            templateUrl:  '/Common/RobotsTextFile' 
                   }
                    }
                })
```

When I hit http://domain/robots.txt, it does hit common controller, but it just return all full html content without robots content.

What can I do to push out only plain/text in Angularjs when everything seems to put into `<div ui-view="main" class="shuffle-animation"></div>`

The result should be like http://demo.nopcommerce.com/robots.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have much to do with AngularJS.

Do not write directly to the response stream, let ASP.NET MVC handle it:

```
return Content("whatever you want", "text/plain");
```

That way you will just get the string out from the method.

Comment: return Content won't give me only plain/text. It stills carry html body from master page. In MVC, Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            Response.Write(sb.ToString()); will ignore site page structure. But now it won't work in Angular

Comment: ContentResult will not cause layout to be called, since there is no View. It only returns the content you want. And AngularJS is only run in the browser, so since there is no View, there is no AngularJS to worry about. There is something very wrong with your setup if you get a view from a ContentResult.

Comment: stupid me, i complated things up by putting the routing into ui-route, just use mvc is enough. Thanks for your help.