# How to define robots.txt for anguluarjs application

Tags: angularjs, google-search, robots.txt, google-search-console

I want defined robots.txt as you can see below to block robots from `login` url:

```
user-agent: *
disallow: /#!/login

Sitemap: http://mysite.ir/sitemap.xml
```

but google does not recognize `#` sign and ignore whole the site. how can i fix that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` as you can see below:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myapp').config(stateConfig);

    function stateConfig($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    }
})();
```

and set this in `head` section of index.html:

```
<base href="/">
```

with this changes angularjs removes `#` from urls in the, keep in mind that you should make some changes in server side.

Answer (score 0):

As per i know angularJS is not good for SEO but yet you can do some basic SEO.

Anyway, this post may help you to create robots.txt [Robot.txt in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207503/how-to-return-plain-text-robots-txt-in-angularjs)